# Как сделать так, чтобы программа была несворачиваемой?

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы программа была несворачиваемой? Кнопке свертки убрал (правый верхний угол, кнопка "-"), но все равно если нажать на иконку в панеле задач, то программа свёртывается.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно. Это фича операционной системы. Любое окно можно свернуть. На Windows это сочетание клавиш <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Ответ автору не очень-то и поможет. К тому же, я не стал бы так торопиться. Можно сделать так, чтобы окно нельзя было закрыть, со свёртыванием должно быть так же. Например, нельзя *свернуть* окно выбора файлов, можно только "загородить" другим окном.

Comment: @Зонтик потому что это **модальное** окно. Для обычных окон это не сработает. Это связано с безопасностью.

Comment: @Зонтик вы знаете что такое модальное окно?

Comment: @Зонтик вы не разобрались. Нажмите Win+D и оно также свернётся.

Comment: А что если прослушивать нажатие клавиш и после win+ d снова поднимать окно? Или раз в x секунд/миллисекунд проверять, является ли окно свёрнутым и разворачивать его обратно? Нельзя же так быстро сдаваться!

Comment: @Зонтик это 1) костыль 2) не получится 3) нарушает безопасность 4) баннеры - плохая практика. Если вы считаете иначе, пожалуйста, предоставьте полноценный ответ, а не пишите предположения в комментариях, у нас так не принято.

Comment: Ответ в корне неверный. Вариант @ДмитрийАлексеенко работает - и ни win+d, ни клик на панели задач не свёртывает окно.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов сделать то, что Вы хотите это сделаю Ваше окно `extends JDialog`
и передать выставить параметр `alwaysOnTop`, но есть нюанс, который заключается в том, что на панели задач (нижняя часть экрана) Windows не будет отображаться иконка, но это окно будет всегда поверх всех и его нельзя свернуть.

Вот кода с простым примером:

```
JDialog rm = new JDialog();
rm.setSize(300, 300);
rm.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // чтобы отображать по середине экрана
rm.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // данный параметр всегда будет держать это окно поверх всего
rm.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю это не JavaFX? У меня на FX написан уже довольно не маленький интерфейс - переписывать долго.

Comment: @АлексейЧ. мне кажется, что переписывать ничего не придётся. javafx - более мощная штука, чем swing, поэтому что-то как минимум такое же (а может и лучше) там точно есть. **P.S** проверил это решение - реально работает!

Comment: Сомневаюсь. В FX мы же отображаем stage с напиханными в него элементами. А сам этот stage  уже является не диалоговым окном. К нему - без проблем. Хоть модальные, хоть диалоговые, хоть что.

Comment: @АлексейЧ. извиняюсь, не увидел тэг `JavaFX`
У класса `Stage` так же имеется метод `setAlwayOnTop`, но у меня небольшой опыт работы с `JavaFX` и я его не применял у `Stage`.

Comment: @АлексейЧ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819194/javafx-2-2-stage-always-on-top как вариант, может это направит у нужное русло.

Comment: setAlwayOnTop - делает приложение поверх всех окон. Но сворачивать его все равно можно. Тут задача стоит что бы окно было не только поверх всех окон(это уже я сделал), но и было не сворачиваемое. Со сворачиваемостью я пока борюсь тем что проверяю свернуто ли оно и если свернуто то разворачиваю. Но, тут появилась другая беда - при разворачивании окна сбивается фокус ввода с того приложения с которым работал пользователь. В идеале нужно что то типа виджетов которые были в виндовс 7(вроде)

Comment: @АлексейЧ. зачем вам это?

Comment: Программа отслеживает наличие интернет соединения. Что бы когда клиент пытается оплатить по карте не было сюрпризом для кассира что интернета нет. А так у него постоянно в углу висит либо зеленый круг либо красный. И надо что бы он ни как не мог его выключить, свернуть, спрятать и прочее. Что бы не было возможности сказать - я не видел, оно не работает и тп. Там специфика продаж есть. Фейерверки.  Буквально пару дней в году кормят весь год. И такие проблемы должны моментально решатся.

Comment: @АлексейЧ. при setAlwaysOnTop() окно (по крайней мере модальное) нельзя свернуть **P.S** проверял на swing.

Comment: @АлексейЧ. появилась идея: скрыть иконку на панели задач Windows, то есть никто не сможет нажать на неё + скрыта кнопка свернуть, а метод setAlwaysOnTop позволит окно держать поверх других

Comment: Скажите как. Не нашел как это можно сделать. А так решение вполне норм. Панель с кнопкой свертки я убрал. Приложение всегда  поверх остальных. Так что скрытие иконки в панели задач вполне себе решение.

Comment: @АлексейЧ. Может этот вариант подойдёт https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712293/how-can-i-remove-my-javafx-program-from-the-taskbar

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко миллион спасибо вам!!!!! Это реально классный вариант. Прям слов нет как я Вам благодарен!!!!!

Comment: @АлексейЧ. Рад помочь)